# Reading large files for ETL program POC

Tags: .net, performance

I'm looking for some information on how to increase the performance of reading large text files for use in an ETL process.

We're currently using a proprietary program that is more of a scripting language that gets converted into C++ and compiled into an executable.  The only redeeming factor that this program has is it's ability to cycle through a 19gig file and populate 250+ fields very quickly.

Where it bogs down is the transformations which, due to the scripting nature of it, tend to be inefficient, cumbersome, and difficult to maintain.

I'm able to parse the text file using .NET (VB or C#) but I'm unable to even come close to the efficiency of the C++ for reading the file, literally hours vs minutes.

I also considered using the data warehouse which loads the same extract I'm reading but for some reason the data warehouse team created one large table that contains millions of rows and all 250+ fields.  Since I need about 150 or so of the fields for the transformations, the queries are excessively slow.

Comment: Do you have access to the generated C++ code?  Reading that would be painful, but it might help.

Comment: This might be helpful - try to create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Even if you don't post it here, the act of making it might help you solve your problem.

Comment: what does POC stand for? Proof Of Concept?

Comment: How are you reading the file in .Net?  IO operation are pretty quick, maybe some sample code will help.

Comment: Have you tried searching SO? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161895/reading-large-text-files-with-streams-in-c-sharp) mentions using `BufferedStream` in certain .NET versions and TPL Dataflow, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030847/best-way-to-read-a-large-file-into-byte-array-in-c) mentions chunking.

Comment: When it is really hours vs. minutes, your C# code is badly written, and there is nothing we can do about it here except guessing around since we don't know your code. Either post some relevant parts of the code in a new question on stackoverflow.com, or use a profiler to find the hotspots (probably best would be both).

Comment: Doc Brown is exactly right. .net can be fast when used properly.